# Replace copy by xcopy, how to handle non-existing directory

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, windows-vista

On some Windows environments (Windows 7 and Windows Vista), I have some scripts running and one of the things those scripts are doing, is trying to copy files. The results of those commands are logged in a logfile.

While looking into that logfile, I've just seen the following result:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

This obviously is not very helpful (which file does he try to copy, to which directory, ...), so I would like to replace the existing `copy` commands by `xcopy` or other commands (in order to use the `xcopy /F` flag, which shows all files and directories of the `xcopy` command), but there is a catch: when I simply replace `copy` by `xcopy` then the non-existing directory gets created, which I don't want (and I don't find a `xcopy` flag to prevent this), so now my question becomes:

Is there a commandline command which tries to copy a file to a directory, which shows the files/directories he's copying but which does not create a destination directory in case it does not exist?

Thanks

Comment: It's giving information indeed, but so is a normal `xcopy` without the preceeding `echo`, in top of that it's also creating the %dest1% directory, which I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd script that like

```
copy %file% %dest% || echo copy of %file% failed>>logfile.log
```

which logs a message when `copy` returns an error (errorlevel <> 0).

Comment: I was looking for some kind of parameter, switch, robocopy example but this will do the trick too. :-) Thanks.